# Primefaces Sortable dataGrid component not possible?

Tags: primefaces

I looked over the component showcase and documentation and maybe I missed it but I was looking to make a component sortable, especially the dataGrid or dataList. The pick list has the sortable behavior but I don't see how to make it work like a sortable dataGrid or dataList. Something similar to this http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/

I currently have two parts of the page. The bottom part is a draggable set of images and the top part is the drop zone to add those images to. Once I drag from the bootom to the top drop zone I want to be able to let the user reorder those images up top..

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this [Drag&Drop example](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/droppableBarca.jsf) from Primefaces Showcase will help you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Matt, but unfortunately it doesn't.  I have a basic drag and drop implemented.  The problem comes that I need to arrange within the dropabble...its more like the picklist http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/picklist.jsf

Comment: But in the example you can sort the players in the droppable once they are there.

Comment: I can only drop/add them to the boxes on the right and not resort them once I drop them there...looks like a feature request has been put in      http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=1744

Comment: I can sort them. It seems there are some conditions that not all players can be dropped to all positions. E.g. if I add Puyol (Germans will never forget him :-) and Abidal. I can move the after dropped. I use Chrome.

Comment: I see what you're saying, but I think its more of a bug...unfortunately.