# Sorting/Reordering a Primefaces Datagrid

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datagrid, jquery-ui-sortable

Building upon the questions [Primefaces Sortable dataGrid component not possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5373719/primefaces-sortable-datagrid-component-not-possible) and [is it possible to sort primefaces Datagrid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11429880/is-it-possible-to-sort-primefaces-datagrid), is there by now any Primefaces option to sort items in a datagrid like in the [jQuery UI showcase](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#display-grid)?

I've googled a lot and played around with `draggable` and `droppable` and [Primefaces orderList](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/orderList.xhtml) in combination with some CSS layout, but none of the options is working the way I expect it to work: [like the datatable](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/reorder.xhtml).

So has there been any progress or some nice workaround I've been missing?

Answer (score 1):

No, there has not been any progress in this area. As can be concluded by lack of info in the showcase, documentation, blog, issuelist, releasenotes.

I've not seen any nice workarounds either as be concluded by missing results when using a generic searchengine.

Or try using this: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panel/dashboard.xhtml

Comment: That was also my impression, I was just hoping that maybe I was missing the right keyword for searching or anything like this. In my experimentations the dashboard approach had its shortcomings when having dynamic data, especially when the backing data list got updated. But maybe I will fiddle a way around that ...

Comment: My "final" solution (well, at least for as long as there is no sortable datagrid) was to use an OrderList with corresponding CSS styling, as it is used in the jQuery showcase. Works for now.